# objective c importing images from twitter to iphone app

Tags: iphone

i want to integrate twitter into my iphone application so i read this good tutorial from Ray wenderlich
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5
,but here what i want to do is that when user selects any image from his twitter account (after logging in to twitter from my app) i want to import that image into my app and display it, i am new to this, can anyone guide me in this plz. thanx and Regards Saad.

Comment: What do you mean by "import it"? Are you wanting to download it and save it locally to your devive or just open a view so that you can zoom in and look around the image?

Comment: No i want to download it and save it, and at the same time also want to display it, from where i saved that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Twitter APIs to handle this.  You need to authenticate using OAuth and you can use the APIs directly.  If it is public data you need not get authorization.  Read about OAuth.  There are good tutorial on OAuth by apigee team on Youtube.  They will get you help started.  There is also a book on Auth2.0.

Comment: Thanx Satish can u tell me the name of that book plz.

Comment: Getting started with OAuth 2.0 by Ryan Boyd.